# Hide DIV if function is empty

Tags: php, function, if-statement, null

let's say I have the following code, how can I hide the DIV if the function is empty?

Similarly, how can I show another DIV if the function is empty?

```
<div class='box12'>
<h1>text<h1/>
<p><?php echo name5(); ?><p/>
</div>
```

Here is my function, for reference (it is returning a term meta field of a taxonomy in wordpress):

```
function regular_tran() {
                $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'regularb');
                $result = "";
                if (is_array($terms) || is_object($terms)){
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $term_id = $term->term_id;
                    $result .= get_term_meta( $term_id, 'tran_65583', true );
                }
            }
                return $result;
            }
```

Comment: what is an empty function ?

Comment: This seems like an X/Y issue. Can you post your full issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the function returns something, then show the div if it does:

```
<?php
$name = name5();

if ($name) {
?>
    <div class='box12'>
        <h1>text</h1>
        <p><?php echo htmlentities($name); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I've also cleaned up your h1 and p ending tags. The `htmlentities` call is included to avoid issues where someone could insert HTML tags in their name and execute javascript, etc. through them.

To show a different message div, you can use `else` (or use `!$name` if you only want to show the div if the result evaluates as empty):

```
<?php
$name = name5();

if ($name) {
?>
    ...
<?php
} else {
?>
    <div>shown if empty</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to turn the function into a $variable to do this or can I do it without that?

Comment: If the function is cheap, i.e. it doesn't involve an external resource like the database, etc., you can call the function multiple times instead. Replace `$name` with the function call `name5()` in that case.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by external resource. I added my function to the original question.

Comment: Meaning that it hits the database, a web service etc. Your function definition seems to indicate that it's a wordpress plugin / theme, and the `_meta` function does at least hit the database each time you use it. So no, you want to avoid calling the function more than once.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks! Do you recommend that I just use a variable instead of a function to begin with? If so how should I code it?

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work right away. I had to add this to make it work: if($name == "" && $name == NULL){....

Answer (score 0):

Server code must spit out something for client javascript code. Change your code:

```
<p><?php echo name5(); ?><p/>
```

to something like:

```
<p>
<?php if (!name5()){ ?>
<script>
$(".box12").hide(); // asuming you are using jQuery
</script>
<?php } ?>
<p/>
```

Comment: you don't require javascript here. As long as the block is encased in a php if, it won't show

Comment: @Juakali92 Well, it depends on a particular use case. This is just elementary example of how server side "talks" to client side. It's fully valid though answer by MatsLindh is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the returned result of the function with an `IF` statement

```
<?php
$result = name5();
if ($result && $result !== '') { ?>
<div class='box12'>
    <h1>text<h1/>
    <p><?php echo $result ?><p/>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try these methods.

```
 1-
    <div class="box12">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <?php if(function_exists('name5')) { ?> 
        <p><?php echo name5(); ?></p>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    2-
    <div class="box12">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <?php if(name5()) { ?> 
        <p><?php echo name5(); ?></p>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>

    3-
    <div class="box12">
      <h1>text</h1>
        <?php $css = (name5()) ? "block":"none"; ?>
        <p style="display:<?=$css?>" >
          <?php echo name5(); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why did you give a minus? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I haven't down-voted your answer, but it is likely that it is because your answer lacks explanation. Answers are more useful if they are specific. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will pay attention.